# Bootstrap slider How can I move the tooltip value to external one?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-slider

I'm using the [**Bootstrap slider**](https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider) plugin to create a **Range Slider**

in **Example 2** I want to remove the `tooltip` option and move the value to external one.

**Here my code :**

**HTML**

```
<b class="min">$ 10</b> 
<input id="example2" type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" data-slider-tooltip="hide" /> 
<b class="max">$ 1000</b>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var slider = new Slider('#example2', {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `slide` event to get current value and embed the value where you want :

```
slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
    //do stuff here
});
```

You can see here Snippet example :

```js
$(function() {

  var slider = new Slider('#example2', {});

  slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
    document.getElementById("value").textContent = sliderValue;
  });

})
```

```css
#value {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/11.0.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>

<b class="min">$ 10</b>
<input id="example2" type="text" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
<b class="max">$ 1000</b>

<br><br> value :
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: I have simple Question How I can implement this to achieve this result https://i.imgur.com/WGgdi34.png